# Running apktool on aws server causes err=2 / err=13

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aapt

I am trying to decompile and recompile back an apk on my aws server.
I am using an apktool for that and it seems to be working properly on my local machine. On the server thought I am able to decompile but I can not recompile it back as I am getting this error:

```
>> java -jar apktool/apktool.jar b decompiled_apk_folder
I: Using Apktool 2.2.0
I: Checking whether sources has changed...
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec: [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_7342825870469849287.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 16, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.1.3, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL5650064046902136421.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /decompile_apk_folder/res, -M, /decompile_apk_folder/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:473)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:407)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:306)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:263)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:224)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec: [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_7342825870469849287.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 16, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.1.3, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL5650064046902136421.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /decompile_apk_folder/res, -M, /decompile_apk_folder/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:439)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:459)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec: [/tmp/brut_util_Jar_7342825870469849287.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 16, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.1.3, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL5650064046902136421.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /decompile_apk_folder/res, -M, /decompile_apk_folder/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:97)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:433)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/brut_util_Jar_7342825870469849287.tmp": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:90)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 8 more
```

I have android sdk on the server with build tools and aapt, and the PATH variable is properly set with platform-tools and tools directories. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I also tried downloading a prebuilt aapt and mentioning it in a parameter:

```
java -jar apktool/apktool.jar --aapt /absolute/path/to/aapt_dir b decompiled_apk_folder
```

but then I got permission denied exception although running as **root** (sudo su -):

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/absolute/path/to/aapt_dir": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:90)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Apktool copies a binary (`aapt`) that it needs to execute to a temporary location based on the Java environmental variable (TMP_DIR) and removes it after completion. This looks like a poor choice for use on an AWS system.

Apktool can either be updated to identify its use on Amazon systems and place the binary in maybe a home folder (~) or you can manually download the aapt [1] binary for the system (unix) and use the parameter `--aapt path/to/aapt/binary` to prevent apktool from doing it automatically.

[1] https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/tree/master/brut.apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/resources/prebuilt/aapt

Comment: Thanks Connor, regretfully I tried it (following this link: https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/997) but instead of "tmp/brut..." I get "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "aapt_dir": error=2, No such file or directory". Maybe I am running the parameter wrong. I tried all variants of "java -jar apktool/apktool.jar --aapt aapt_dir/ b decompiled_apk_folder" where the downloaded aapt is in aapt_dir folder.

Comment: @MikeL Try passing the full path (including the aapt) binary itself. The parameter might be misleading, but currently it relies on the value being the path to the aapt binary (not folder).

Comment: Please see the edit. 10 min ago realized that this might be the issue and indeed now i get permission denied err=13 instead of err=2 and although running as root still get this error. Running with the aapt file in the path causes err=2 so i think without the file is the proper way. Thank you for the suggestions. I feel that I am almost there :)

Comment: Can it be a ia32-libs issue? Although permission exception is not leading to that...

Comment: @MikeL possible, but the error when not having 32bit libraries is usually different than the above.